# How can I capture the iPhone home screen as an image?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I would like to use an image of the home screen in my application.  How can I capture the iPhone home screen as an image when my application runs?

Answer (score 1):

I want to give you a simple and short answer: "This is not possible"

While your app is running, you can't get access to other apps (in this case to the SpringBoard.app).

Answer (score 0):

Open XCode Organizer, Devices tab, hit the screenshot button.

Or simply press the "Home" and "Sleep/Power" buttons at the same time, which will take a screenshot anywhere and save it to your photo roll.

Comment: i want to take a picture in runtime.